# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority CMD K6.io

Tags: soap, soapui, load-testing, k6

I am presently using a nice tool to perform performance testing (load) for a project via a VPN. I am using K6.io and SOAPUI.  run the same tool using both tools just to compare results. K6.io is a Javascript library that gathers robust configurable metrics, and likewise SOAPUI. The challenge is that SOAPUI works smoothly while K6.io always hit a certificate issue. Since SOAPUI works fine I believe the problem is either certificate issue with my system or K6.io. I'm yet to figure out what the real problem is.

The main reason why I like k6.io is because of the robust reporting tools it integrates with like InfluxDB and Grafana. It is because I have to generate graphical reports for the test.

Error from k6.io CMD

```
    script: AccountClosure.js
     output: -

  scenarios: (100.00%) 1 scenario, 1 max VUs, 10m30s max duration (incl. graceful stop):
           * default: 1 iterations for each of 1 VUs (maxDuration: 10m0s, gracefulStop: 30s)

WARN[0002] Request Failed                                error="Post \"https://mysite.behindvpn.com:4333/fiwebservice/services/FIPWebService\": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
d
running (00m01.8s), 0/1 VUs, 1 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default ✓ [======================================] 1 VUs  00m01.4s/10m0s  1/1 iters, 1 per VU
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don’t want to run with `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` 9, I think your only option is to add the root CA certificate to your local store.

On Linux this would involve the ca-certificates package and copying your cert to the correct location. This will be system dependent, but see the instructions for Ubuntu 5, otherwise consult your OS documentation.

Ivan

https://community.k6.io/t/x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority/1057/2?u=ken4ward